# How to add element to row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add an element to a row with a None element like the following.

```
    first   second third
0   100     2      212
1   212     NaN    213
```

```
    first   second third
0   100     2      212
1   212     23    213
```

How would I be able to do this without adding the new row entirely?

Comment: [df.iat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html)

Comment: Use `df = df.fillna(23)`

Comment: @BeRT2me how would I be able to specify the column name "second" instead of the index of column?

Comment: [df.at](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html#pandas-dataframe-at)